# Android ListFragment, new items appear at bottom of list

Tags: android, list, fragment, populate

I'm new to Eclipse and Android app development. Been trying to solve this issue for two days now but with no luck. Surfed the net and documentation for... many hours. :S

I have a ListFragment and a Button enclosed in RelativeLayout. The button is located below the list and the list is intially empty at app startup which is what i want. I'm using an ArrayAdapter and my items (String objects for now) are inside an ArrayList.

When I click the button, the list is updated with the new item and everything works fine except that new items show up **at the bottom** of the visible list, just above the button. If i click once more on my button, a new item shows up at the bottom of the list, and the first item is moved above the second item. Why is that and how do i fix it? I want the first item to show up at the top of the list, second item below that item, third one below the second one and so on.

What i do when i add an item is simply adding an item to beginning of my list of objects and then call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged().

How do i specify that new items in my empty ListFragment list should appear at the very top of the list?

Been playing around with different TRANSCRIPT_MODE but that didn't help. The solution is probably trivial... but i just can't find the solution. Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer my own question here.

Change of

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

to

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

in the **fragment** XML tag fixed it. What I still don't understand is why wrap_content makes list items show up at bottom of the screen first. Maybe some bug with how wrap_content works with initially empty lists when used in a ListFragment?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add items to the top of your `ListView`, you need to **insert the items at the top** of your items-list.

```
List items = new ArrayList();

for(Object obj : objectList) { // objectlist is a list of new items
    items.add(0, obj); // INSERT AT TOP
    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. The thing is, i'm already doing that. The exact same code is working fine if i make a simple MainActivity, define a ListView and try to populate it with my button clicks. However, if i use the ListFragment, and if its empty, and try to add an item, its like the default position in the ListFragment is at the bottom of the visible area of ListFragment. To me, it looks like i should use some kind of option to the Fragment tag in XML, but i dunno.

Answer (score 0):

To make it more clear.

items.add(obj);
This will populate my initial empty list when i click the button repeatedly.

items.add(0, obj);
This will do the same, only the internal order of the items are reversed.

In BOTH cases, the first visible item in the app when it is running, shows up above the Add Button (located at the bottom of screen). I want the first item to show up just below the ActionBar. The ListFragment is inside a relative layout and is defined like this

```
<!-- this file is included in both single-pane and two-pane versions of the layout-->
<!-- i use merge to avoid code duplication -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_add"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="@string/button_add"/>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/item_list"
        android:name="com.example.test.ItemListFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/button_add"
        tools:context=".ItemListActivity"
        tools:layout="@android:layout/list_content"/>
</merge>
```